# Matching concatenated substrings (in any order) of two words separated by any character in C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

Having two strings as parameters `(s1, s2)` I should be able to set up a `new Regex(my_regular_expression(s1, s2))`. For example s1="abcd", s2="xyz" I would like to match strings:

> regex.IsMatched(x)==true, where x is one of the following:

```
abcd.xyz
abcd-xyz
xyzabcd
dxy
yzab
z a
dx
cd
but not limited to
```

but `regex.IsMatched(y)==false`, where y is one of the following:

```
aabcd.xyzv
abd.xyz
xycd
but not limited to
```

Between s1 and s2 there could be nothing or any character. Any right substring (see the function `string.right(string str,int length)` ) of s1 concatenated with a left substring (see the function `string.left(string str,int length)` ) of s2 or any right substring of s2 concatenated with a left substring of s1.

Please use s1 and s2 in regex not abcd, xyz. s1/s2 can contain special characters.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would `dxy` match but not `aabcd.xyzv`? What about `xycd`? Can you update the question with a more complete definition of what the regex is supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Combined` would give you the expression you want. It has the following limitations.

- It currently allows *any* character to combine the two halves (the `.` or `-` in your examples), even if it's a letter.
- `SuffixPart` does not support Unicode characters which do not fit in a single UTF-16 code point. If you need to handle this edge case, [here is a related question that talks about Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476535/how-to-get-a-reversed-string-unicode-safe/7476639#7476639).
- For that matter `PrefixPart` also does not support Unicode characters which are not a single UTF-16 code point, but that method is not broken "as badly".

Here is the code:

```
public static string PrefixPart(string str)
{
    return
        string.Join("(?:", str.Select(i => Regex.Escape(i.ToString())))
        + string.Join(")?", Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, str.Length));
}

public static string SuffixPart(string str)
{
    return PrefixPart(new string(str.Reverse().ToArray()));
}

public static string Combined(string str1, string str2)
{
    string left = SuffixPart(str1) + ".?" + PrefixPart(str2);
    string right = SuffixPart(str2) + ".?" + PrefixPart(str1);
    return string.Format("^{0}|{1}$", left, right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
"/" + s1 + ".?" + s2 + "|" + s2 + ".?" + s1 + "/"
```

This would evaluate to (in your example):

```
/abcd.?xyz|xyz.?abcd/
```

That is both required patterns in either order separated by zero or one of any character.

Comment: This is not working for my examples: check http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: @algorytmus I was able to get it to work just fine, but that site doesn't have permalinks.  Here: http://rubular.com/r/qFX5Ib4Kog

Comment: Get rid of the `"/"` at either end.  C#/.NET doesn't require you to enclose the regex in delimiters like some other flavors do.

Comment: But "dxy" and "yzab" are not matched

Comment: @algorytmus why would you expect either of those to be matched?  Maybe your rules are unclear to me